# Innodb deadlock, looks like tx locks itself

Tags: mysql, innodb, deadlock

I get a deadlock error, but don't understand why. Below report shows, that the second transaction (..453, that is rolled back), has already a lock on *"space id 545 page no 7185 n bits 192 index `PRIMARY` of table `orders`.`order_items`"* and **is waiting to get lock on exactly the same**.

The first one, ...455 also wants to get the same lock, but it can wait, no problem...

So it looks like transaction ..453 locks itself??

```
------------------------
LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK
------------------------
2017-04-13 10:55:21 7f434dd30700
*** (1) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 108696455, ACTIVE 0 sec starting index read
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 5 lock struct(s), heap size 1184, 4 row lock(s), undo log entries 2
MySQL thread id 652170, OS thread handle 0x7f434ca25700, query id 268182543 10.9.14.13 orders updating
delete from order_items where id=13828382 and version='2017-04-11 12:28:02'
*** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 545 page no 7185 n bits 192 index `PRIMARY` of table `orders`.`order_items` trx id 108696455 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap waiting
*** (2) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 108696453, ACTIVE 0 sec starting index read
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
5 lock struct(s), heap size 1184, 7 row lock(s), undo log entries 5
MySQL thread id 652151, OS thread handle 0x7f434dd30700, query id 268182547 10.9.14.11 orders updating
delete from order_items where id=13828386 and version='2017-04-11 12:28:02'
*** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 545 page no 7185 n bits 192 index `PRIMARY` of table `orders`.`order_items` trx id 108696453 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap
*** (2) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 545 page no 7185 n bits 192 index `PRIMARY` of table `orders`.`order_items` trx id 108696453 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap waiting
*** WE ROLL BACK TRANSACTION (1)
```

Edit: Table create code:

```
CREATE TABLE `order_items` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `order_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `catalog_number` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `posex` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `sap_item_name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `currency` varchar(3) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `price` decimal(19,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `quantity` decimal(19,10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `parent_item_posex` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `deleted` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `version` datetime NOT NULL,
  `created_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `FKbioxgbv59vetrxe0ejfubep1w` (`order_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FKbioxgbv59vetrxe0ejfubep1w` FOREIGN KEY (`order_id`) REFERENCES `orders` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `order_items_ibfk_1`          FOREIGN KEY (`order_id`) REFERENCES `orders` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=14564054 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE order_items`.

Comment: Hi @RickJames, i have added the create code, thanks for checking!

Comment: A guess:  2 identical FK constaints?

Comment: Thanks @RickJames, it looks like it was that...

Comment: Bad luck, @RickJames, it was not that... the same deadlock situation happened again...

Comment: You could try filing a bug at http:bugs.mysql.com .  I don't know the internals well enough to answer your question; they do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Rick James guessed, it looks like it was simply a double identical key. At least after removing one of the constraints problem did not occur on that table anymore.

Comment: "Learn something new every day."  It really was a guess.

Comment: It surprised me too since the deadlock report suggested problem with primary key, not foreign. But in the meantime i learned that those reports are often very misleading...